# Is there some utility function to identify whether the code is running on Emulator or Hardware?

Tags: android

My requirement is to call a particular variant of a function if it is Emulator and a different 
variant it is Hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code (and you get code to pull serial number too)

```
public static String getDeviceSerialNumber(Context ctx)
    {
        String phoneSerial = null;

        try
        {
            phoneSerial = ((TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            phoneSerial = null;
        }

        //If it's not a phone or for some reason we can't get serial/IMEI - get serial from
        if (phoneSerial == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
                Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);
                phoneSerial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno");
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }


        return phoneSerial;
    }

    public static boolean isRunningInEmulator(Context ctx)
    {
        return "000000000000000".equals(getDeviceSerialNumber(ctx));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Build.DEVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#DEVICE).

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
String bpStr = Build.PRODUCT;
if ("google_sdk".equals(bpStr))
  // IT'S RUNNING ON THE EMULATOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other options seem better in my opinion, because you never know if future devices will omit including this, you can also check for an accelerometer sensor. Emulators wont support one, and currently all phones that have android market and google native apps have an accelerometer.

In onCreate, after implementing SensorEventListener;

```
    SensorManager manager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (manager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() == 0) {
            textView.setText("No accelerometer installed"); 
    }
```